# In SSRS, how do I compare a value of a parent report item with report items in a child group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, report-builder2.0

I am using SSRS 2008. I have 3 different groups above my report details that are calculated sums. I am trying to color the limit red if any of the invoice sums(A) in a child group is above the limit(B).

I am currently using this expression, but it is only looking at the first or last invoice amount. The limit report item is in a parent group just above the invoice's group.

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Invoice_DueDate.Value>ReportItems!Limit.Value,"Red","Black")
```

[image]

**My Solution:** I decided to use SQL to get the sum of the invoice amount grouped by due date. I then called that field in the parent group.

Comment: I decided to use SQL to get the sum of the invoice amount grouped by due date. I then called that field in the parent group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think you can use

```
=IIF(MAX(ReportItems!Invoice_DueDate.Value) > ReportItems!Limit.Value,"Red","Black")
```

You need some sort of aggregate function, such as `MAX()` to tell SSRS what the scope and operation of what should be done. (For example if you wanted to make sure the total didn't exceed the limit, you would use `SUM(...)`

Comment: I tried this solution, but I received an error.

The Expression: =IIF(MAX(ReportItems!Invoice_DueDate.Value)>ReportItems!Limit.Value,"Red","Black")

The Error: [rsAggregateReportItemInBody] The Color expression for the textrun 'Limit.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference parent groups from a child group using aggregate expressions specifying the parent group Scope.

For example, say we have some simple data:

[image]

And a simple table based on this, with a group based on `grp`.

[image]

Here the **BackgroundColor** property for the `value` textbox in the detail row is set as:

```
=IIf(Fields!value.Value > Min(Fields!limit.Value, "Group1")
  , "Red"
  , Nothing)
```

This checks all rows in the parent group of the current row, not just the current row. This works as expected:

[image]

Without knowing your data it's impossible to say if this will work in your case, but hopefully it gives you something to consider.

**Edit after comments**

OK, based on further comments it seems like you need aggregate on aggregate functionality.

This is available via SSRS expressions in 2008R2 and above only, so this won't help in your case.

For older versions, your best option might be to add an extra field to your Dataset that supplies the maximum `Invoice` value for each group, and then you can use this value without issues in the parent group.

There are some workarounds around that suggest using custom code to do this, such as [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4a3969a-f3fc-457b-8430-733d7b590ff6/use-reportitems-to-sum-all-textboxes-in-a-tablix), but I've never used this suggested solution and would only even consider it if you don't have any control over the report Dataset.

Comment: The data is in a decimal format (1200000.00),but the report items are formatted to show a dollar amount.                                                      


Here is the expression I tried:

=IIF(MAX(ReportItems!Invoice_DueDate.Value, "table1_DueDate")>ReportItems!Limit.Value,"Red","Black")


I tried this solution and I get the following error: [rsAggregateReportItemInBody] The Color expression for the textrun 'Limit.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Comment: In my screenshot, the groups are set up quite a bit different than yours. Thank you for your help Ian.

Comment: In my example, I'm using `Fields!...` references, not `ReportItems!...`, which is why you can use it the property expression. If you supply some sample data which demonstrates your requirements, I could supply some further detail.

Comment: I am wanting to get the max value of the child group to use in the parent group. Your solution is to get a parent group aggregate to use in a child group. I am using `=IIF(MAX(Fields!Invoice.Value,"table1_DueDate")>SUM(Fields!Limit.Value),"Red","Black")` , but I can't seem to get an aggregate function to look in my child group. `table1_DueDate` is the child group or (A). I get the following error: The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Comment: OK, I added a few more details.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to aggregate this in the stored procedure and bring it over to the report in a field. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sadly, for 2008 and below that's probably the only foolproof option.